# axios post / get always return 404 in react

Tags: reactjs, fastapi, redux-saga

```
// Login Method
const postLogin = (url, data) => {
    return axios.post(url, data).then(response => {
        if (response.status === 400 || response.status === 500)
            throw response.data;
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        throw err[1];
    });
}
```

The above login method always log the following error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createAxiosError (utils.js:147:1)
    at Object.settle (utils.js:123:1)
    at handleRequest (handle_request.js:124:1)
    at index.js:26:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MockAdapter.<anonymous> (index.js:25:1)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:52:1)
```

On call

```
const response = yield call(postLogin, 'http://localhost:8080/users/verify_login/', {
                 email: user.username, 
                 password: user.password, 
                 headers: {
                     "Content-Type": "application/json",
                     "accept" : "application/json",
                 }});
```

Though the `http://localhost:8080` is running. We are using React. How to solve this?

Comment: If the code `404` in your API actually means `Not Found` it might be cause the user is not in the database?

Comment: @Croolman the user is in database I got response with `curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/users/verify_login/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "email": "rafi@gmail.com",
  "password": "pass"
}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using async await for better debugging your code.

```
const postLogin = async (url, data) => {
   try{
     var response = await axios.post(url, data)
     return response
    }catch(e){
      // Handle catch
    }finally{
     // Handle finally
    }
}
```